# Convert a value from cm to inch in excel (length - breadth - thickness)

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I want to convert/replace the numbers

Original cell:

35 - 45 - 12 cm

Looking for conversion in next cell:

14 - 18 - 5 inch

There are many cells in this format. Anyone??

Comment: Do each of the affected cells contain a string which consists exactly of two digits, a dash surrounded by single spaces, another two digits, another dash surrounded by single spaces, two final digits, a final space, and the exact characters `c` and `m`? Or do you have a freer format wrt number of spaces, dots after `cm`, or similar?

Comment: On this site you are expected to show what you have tried before you ask a question and post the code that you have come up so far.

Answer (score 1):

I would use User Defined Function for this. Go to VBA and create a new module then copy and paste following function into the module.

```
Function convertToInches(rng As Range)
Dim numbers
Dim i As Integer
Dim ret() As String
    If rng.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        convertToInches = "ERR: Single Cell Required"
    Else
        numbers = Split(rng.Value, " ")
        For i = 0 To UBound(numbers)
            ReDim Preserve ret(i)
            If IsNumeric(numbers(i)) Then
                ret(i) = Round(Application.WorksheetFunction.Convert(numbers(i), "cm", "in"), 0)
            Else
                ret(i) = numbers(i)
            End If
        Next i
        convertToInches = Join(ret, " ")
    End If
End Function
```

Then go back to your worksheet and try it with a cell. If A1 has cm values and you want B1 to be inches, then put following formula into B1:

> =convertToInches(A1)

Note that if you want digits then change 0 in the Round function to be something else.

EDIT for info: It is self descriptive but just in case you are not familiar with VBA then: It takes the range parameter that you give with the formula call and splits it by the spaces in it. Then loop through the array elements split by the spaces then check if the current item is number. If it is then it thinks it is a number to be converted and convert, if not then it keeps it intact in the same order. Then it joins these elements (numbers as converted) and sends it back to the caller cell that you wrote the formula as the desired result. Hope it helps. Same can be done with formulas without VBA. And be careful, I assumed at least one space around the numbers.

Comment: This site is not a free code writing service. Unfortunately, answers like yours will encourage people to keep treating it like one.

Comment: @teylyn If there is something I am playing against this site's rules that I am not aware then please show me what it is so I'll surely correct what I've been possibly doing wrong from this point. You might have been partially right if I did like many people around and didn't dedicate MY time to explain what the code I sent as sample was doing but that's also not the case. Please also consider that VBA was not asked in the question, OP might not even knew about UDFs. Now he does and it is good thing.

Comment: You may want to look at the site FAQ about how to ask a good question. This was not a good question and we should encourage good questions rather than answer bad ones. It comes across as rep greedy. But, hey, if that's how you want to play, please go on.